# Inference for Maximum Likelihood Estimator Using Particle Filter

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, inference, fisher-information, particle-filter

How does one compute standard errors for the MLE when using a particle filter approximation to the likelihood? I know that the estimator is asymptotically normal and that the variance-covariance matrix is the inverse of the Fisher information matrix, but in sample what is the equivalent?